# Can we have the old feed back (as an option)?

Tags: feature-request, design, subscription

I've noticed that the feed format has changed. The new format seems inconvenient
to read. The layout is more modern style but the actual facts - which is the question with few words of text - is much less present at the first look. I may simply have to get used to it but I fear that the new style is systematically worse. 
Things to look at:

1. starting with two huge banners providing very little information except the tag.
2. size of feed triple of what the old style was
3. actual content more squeezed into a small box

I'd like to encourage StackExchange to review the design and possibly offer
an "old-style" option.

**Edit: October 16, 2014: The new scheme returned with some minor rendering changes:**

[image]
**Features:**

1. Each mail three times as big; may look neat but takes bytes.
2. Large banner area above then actual content; need to scroll to get there.
3. The actual information contained is less, the StackExchange branch (e.g. stackoverflow.com) and the OP's user name is obviously omitted with the new layout; there is no additional information. In my view the comment by [Matthew](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/241939/190546) in [Egregious whitespace on digest emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240844/190546) does not apply at all.
4. What about code provided in questions? Look at example capture above. Proper code rendering would be smart when rendering shall be really improved. But: Do we want code in the initial "brief" information at all?
5. The only thing added is **fluff** as correctly stated by [svick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240780/190546).
6. It's not my [cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/241943/190546) which was moved here. The **questions** are StackExchange's cheese. StackExchange should be proud of their questions and they should handle them carefully.

[Gyro Gearloose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_Gearloose) said to the fortuneteller: "*You may know all answers, but you don't know all questions.*" However, StackExchange needs people to answer the questions to get more of them. That's why **the way presenting the questions** shall be of utmost priority. People subscribing for e-mail notifications of a tag have already stated their interest in questions. Advertising and/or appealing graphics may destroy this interest in the long term.

I've changed my mind: I don't ask StackExchange to offer an option as written above.

---

Frankly, I ask to simply fix this.

---

P.S.: I appreciate the unscathed survival of the little red **`<3`** at the very end.

Comment: Which feed? I don't think we touched any RSS-related stuff in a while...

Comment: @Anna Lear: I'm getting mail feed from _do-not-reply@stackexchange.com_ for subscribed filters. The mails themselves state the name "feed"

Comment: Ah, emails. Can you forward one of them to me? anna@stackexchange.com. Thanks.

Comment: forwarded with some more thoughts

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: @AnnaLear: I had to edit/update my request due to the fact that the new design returned to be active as of today. However, the proposed modifications are negligible.

Answer (score 11):

To illustrate the point, here is a screenshot of the old format in my GMail:

[image: old format screenshot]

And the new format:

[image: new format screenshot]

In the old format, almost 3 emails fit into a screen and GMail can omit some of the repeated parts (notice those "…"). In the new format, only one email fits into a page, there is lots of empty space and GMail didn't manage to remove the repeated parts.

Comment: We've disabled the new template for now, pending another design pass.

Comment: @Anna: Just noticed the return, deeply appreciated!

Comment: @Arno Can't promise that it'll stay that way, but we're going to try to make it more usable before reenabling the new templates.

Comment: Wow, that's just... awful.  I don't use the e-mail feed myself, but I can see why those who do would be pissed off.  Good to know that it's been reverted.

Answer (score 2):

We turned off the updated email design temporarily to fix a few minor rendering issues (colors, font sizes, etc), but it will be coming back very soon.

I replaced the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag.  The problems you point out are design choices, and may not be interpreted as "problems" by most users.

As a consolation, there *is* a way to [hook up gmail to read rss feeds](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/turn-gmail-into-an-rss-reader-with-ifttt-1582552035) (the gist of which is to set up IFTTT actions).  I know that doesn't change the fact that we [moved your cheese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Moved_My_Cheese%3F), but we think the new template will be more appealing to many users (including me).

**Update**: it's understandable that not everyone will appreciate these changes, which is why I changed this to a feature request.  Also, a user has written what is really the best justification for these changes here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/241939/136973

Comment: The "bug" tag was not my choice. Initially my post had tags "discussion" and "support". It was not my intention to report this as a bug. That's why I asked for a "users choice" with respect to the new design. I'd suggest to consider a "choice" and monitor the stats to find out what's more appealing.

Comment: What's the reason for the change? Is it that you're optimizing for people who receive the emails rarely? If that's the case, maybe each first email in a day could use the new full format, but second and following emails in a day could use a simpler format (similar to the old one)?

Comment: @svick here's the best answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/241939/136973

Comment: @BenCollins That mostly answers "Why not have more content in the emails?". Personally, I don't want *more content*, I want *less fluff*.

Comment: @svick yep, I understand, and I'm sure you won't be the only one that feels that way.  I think the answer addresses this though - the point is to drive engagement, and visual design has a big impact on that.  The thought here is that this will improve overall engagement coming from email subscriptions.

Comment: @Ben: Your goal is more engagement and you hide the actual information in at most 10% of the space available for the entire message? Are you sure that this looks more appealing and thus improves the engagement? Can you please be a bit more specific and extend your answer accordingly?

Comment: @BenCollins: Funny enough, today I received a single message in the old format! Any changes predictable?

Comment: @Amo, There are no changes planned.  If you got an old-style email you should post it as a bug.